# Is there a way to temporarily pause all world/stimulus dynamics in Shady?

Tags: python, shady

I have a Shady script for running an interactive program that involves numerous `Stimulus` objects with multiple dynamic properties. The `World` itself also has some dynamic properties.

I need a way to temporarily stop the interactive program. I can handle this "paused" state myself in my custom `Animate` callbacks attached to the world/stimuli, which are few in number, but it is clearly not ideal to handle it in every single dynamic property function. Is there a way to "pause" and later "unpause" all dynamics simultaneously? Preferably, at least the `World.Animate` callback (and all event handlers) would still be called each frame in this paused state so I can monitor the condition for unpausing and possibly do something different while paused.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the `_FrameCallback` code in the `Shady.Rendering` submodule, it seems there's no *global* flag that says "run animation callbacks but not dynamic property evaluations". There's also no official/documented pathway to doing it.

However, on an instance-by-instance basis there's an unofficial way you could suspend dynamics: just nix out the undocumented `._dynamics` attribute, perhaps storing it somewhere for later reinstatement.  Do the same with the `.Animate` attribute to disable animation callbacks. To disable both types of dynamic together in one fell swoop, how about this:

```
def ToggleDynamics(x):
    x._disabled_dynamics, x._dynamics = x._dynamics, getattr(x, '_disabled_dynamics', {})
    x._disabled_Animate, x.Animate = x.Animate, getattr(x, '_disabled_Animate', None)
```

where `x` is your `World` or `Stimulus` instance. Then, to take this toggle global, you could do:

```
def ToggleDynamicsEverywhere(world):
    for thing in [world] + list(world.stimuli.values()):
        ToggleDynamics(thing)
```

Try that in `python -m Shady shell showcase` and you'll see that `ToggleDynamicsEverywhere(world)` suspends everything except video playback.

There are some fairly obvious ways you could customize these two  functions to unequivocally enable/disable dynamics rather than toggling them, or to operate on all `Stimulus` instances but exclude the `World`, or to disable dynamic-properties-but-not-animation-callbacks or vice versa.

Comment: A quick and dirty alternative is simply to say `world.fakeFrameRate=float('inf')` and that seems to stop time for any dynamic that depends on an input time `t`. But the dynamics are still called, so any changes they cause independent of `t`  will still happen.

Comment: Storing and restoring `_dynamics` works nicely. I'm also recording the duration of the paused period and using it to increment `stimulus.t0` when unpausing, which makes the dynamics act as though the missing time never happened.